# R Left_Join changing values to NA

Tags: r, left-join

Trying to join a large dataframe (~800k Rows) to smaller dataframe (200 Rows). The smaller dataframe contains information specific to each ID and the large dataframe contains timestamps and IDs (along with a couple other columns).

I need to populate the large dataframe with additional columns containing all the information that pertains to the ID listed in each row in the larger dataframe. Each ID can come up multiple times, some IDs that are in the large dataset won't have a match in the smaller dataset, and some in the smaller dataset might not appear in the large dataset.

It is my understanding that using `left_join`  will accomplish what I want to do - fill the information from the smaller table to the large table based on matching IDs.

Here is dput for the large datafame ('Detections')

```
structure(list(TimeStampUTC = structure(c(1686810545, 1686810781, 
1686813684, 1686814523, 1686815237, 1686838317), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), RecType = c("VR2Tx", "VR2Tx", "VR2Tx", 
"VR2Tx", "VR2Tx", "VR2Tx"), RecSerial = c(486553, 486553, 486553, 
486553, 486553, 486553), Transmitter = c("A69-9001-62654", "A69-9001-62654", 
"A69-9001-62624", "A69-9001-62624", "A69-9001-62624", "A69-9001-62624"
), TimeStampLocal = structure(c(1686810545, 1686810781, 1686813684, 
1686814523, 1686815237, 1686838317), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "America/Chicago"), Project = c("Carp1", "Carp1", 
"Carp1", "Carp1", "Carp1", "Carp1"), Deploy = structure(c(1625724061, 
1625724061, 1625724061, 1625724061, 1625724061, 1625724061), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "America/Chicago"), Removal = structure(c(1687327261, 
1687327261, 1687327261, 1687327261, 1687327261, 1687327261), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "America/Chicago"), LocationName = c("Lake Cocodrie", 
"Lake Cocodrie", "Lake Cocodrie", "Lake Cocodrie", "Lake Cocodrie", 
"Lake Cocodrie"), LocationType = c("ICWW", "ICWW", "ICWW", "ICWW", 
"ICWW", "ICWW"), Type = c("Hydrophone", "Hydrophone", "Hydrophone", 
"Hydrophone", "Hydrophone", "Hydrophone"), Structure = c("", 
"", "", "", "", ""), LatitudeDD = c(29.6134, 29.6134, 29.6134, 
29.6134, 29.6134, 29.6134), LongitudeDD = c(-90.9813, -90.9813, 
-90.9813, -90.9813, -90.9813, -90.9813), Status = c("Deployed", 
"Deployed", "Deployed", "Deployed", "Deployed", "Deployed")), row.names = 838196:838201, class = "data.frame")
```

And the small dataframe ("Tagging")

```
structure(list(StudyID = 1:6, Study = c("Coastal Carp", "Coastal Carp", 
"Coastal Carp", "Coastal Carp", "Coastal Carp", "Coastal Carp"
), TimeStampLocal = structure(c(1621949640, 1621949820, 1621950120, 
1621950960, 1621951320, 1621951680), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "America/Chicago"), Transmitter = c("A69-9001-62555", 
"A69-9001-62556", "A69-9001-62557", "A69-9001-62558", "A69-9001-62559", 
"A69-9001-62560"), Species = c("Silver", "Silver", "Silver", 
"Silver", "Bighead", "Silver"), ForkLengthMM = c(990L, 976L, 
982L, 961L, 1141L, 941L), Sex = c("Undetermined", "Undetermined", 
"Undetermined", "Undetermined", "Undetermined", "Undetermined"
), Gear = c("Electroshocking", "Electroshocking", "Electroshocking", 
"Electroshocking", "Electroshocking", "Electroshocking"), StableIsotope = c(NA_integer_, 
NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_
), ReleaseCondition = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L), Latitude = c(29.9292, 
29.9292, 29.9292, 29.9292, 29.9292, 29.9292), Longitude = c(-90.3216, 
-90.3216, -90.3216, -90.3216, -90.3216, -90.3216), ReleaseLocation = c("Davis Pond", 
"Davis Pond", "Davis Pond", "Davis Pond", "Davis Pond", "Davis Pond"
), TaggingHUC6 = c("Central Louisiana Coastal", "Central Louisiana Coastal", 
"Central Louisiana Coastal", "Central Louisiana Coastal", "Central Louisiana Coastal", 
"Central Louisiana Coastal"), Group = c("East", "East", "East", 
"East", "East", "East"), Tagger = c("Christian", "Christian", 
"Christian", "Christian", "Christian", "Christian")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have tried all the joins but each time I complete all the new columns get NA values, and some of the columns from the left (large) dataset that were present the line of code above get transformed to NA. Below is the code that is not only not joining the dataframes, but also changing some of the  data to NA's.

```
D2 <- left_join(Detections, Tagging, by = "Transmitter")
```

Comment: In the code you have posted, neither data set shares a common merge key value (i.e. no values of `Transmitter` are found in both `Detections` and `Tagging`). For this reason all the new columns from `Tagging` that are merged to `Detections` result in `NA`.

Comment: `left_join` on `Detections` will result in a data frame that has the same number of rows and it will add (n - 1) columns, in your case. n being the number of columns in `Tagging` and minus one for the merge column.

Comment: @LMc Thank you for giving it a shot. You are correct for the code I shared. That was mainly just to give you the idea - That code just took the top 5 or 6 values for transmitters so it was easily reproducible. I have a lot of overlapping values. Also, this doesn't explain why join would change all the values in table being joined to to NA values, not just a join that has no matches.

Comment: It will be hard to diagnose unless you can provide example data that recreates the issue. "All the new columns get NA values" is what would happen if `Tagging` did not have the Transmitter values that exactly match the ones in `Detections`. "some of the columns from the left (large) dataset that were present the line of code above get transformed to NA" is mysterious and suggests something else is at play in your creation/modification of `Detections`